# Google Drive REST API - Update File Content

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, google-drive-api, google-api-nodejs-client

I would like to build an "Agreement Generator" for my business that is based on Google Docs Templates. I have a Node.js app that calls the Google Drive REST API v3. Here's how I'd like to do it:

1. Get a Google Document's raw content
2. Replace every `${variable_name}` with `value` in that raw content (value is provided from an HTML form)
3. Update the Google Document raw content

I have been wrapping my head over this for days and I just can't find out how to get a Google Document's raw content.

It seems that all I can get is metadata. Other than that, I was thinking of maybe using the `drive.files.export()` method to get a Word document (to keep formatting and layout) then read it with Node and replace the values. But then I would have to re-upload that Word file and manually re-convert it to a Google Document from the Drive UI.

So I'm stuck there! Has anybody ever done something like that? Please help :)

Comment: It might be easier to do this with Google Apps Script. In GAS there is a 
Document Service that gives you easy access to the document.

Comment: Download the file make the changes upload the file again.   Google Drive does not give you access to edit the contents of a file programmatically its just storage of files.